# MS Word: Create rectangle around words in a paragraph

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, text-formatting

I'm trying to create a document in MS Word that shows a section for keywords. See following pictures:

[image: sample document 1]

And this one:

[image: sample document 2]

It's very easy to create a shape and type text in it and make it a floating shape. What I'm trying to achieve is that I select a single word or group of words and apply some sort of style on it that it shows those words in a box, something like the screenshots. But these boxes need to be on the same line.

I tried to work with floating shapes, it's a headache to align all the shapes together and is not a robust process. Any time there is a change in document, these shapes go out of place.

Is there any solution to this? I have a feeling that I might end up going towards HTML based document, seems like its easier to do this using CSS.

Comment: do you really need round corners? are rectangles around the text OK?

Comment: Did you change the shape properties so they are In Line With Text (rather than any of the other wrapping options) - in line would make it easier for you to work with them on same line.

Comment: Have you looked at Smart Art? Basic Block List may do what you want

Comment: @phuclv Yes I suppose rectangles would also work. Rounded ones would've been better-looking. How to achieve it?

Comment: @Tanya I just tried it out. It seems to be doing something what I was looking for. Now the difficulty is that the shape doesn't automatically resize according to the text I'm typing in it. I enabled the shape property "Resize shape to fit text" but that's not working properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add borders around the texts by clicking the Border button in Paragraphs group

[image: Border feature]

For more control over formatting click on *Border and Shading* in the same menu. You can choose to have color for the background (shading) and border, as well as border style. To set if the border should go around your selected text or the whole containing paragraph you can use the *"Applies to"* feature

[image: Border setting]

You can also nest borders (text and paragraph) like the above screenshot. Borders and shading that apply to paragraph will be bigger and will the whole page width

Comment: This is also a good solution. But I prefer the solution by @Tanya above to use shape as in-line layout. That worked for me. Thanks.